# Query criteria in subclass on Grails 3

Tags: grails, groovy, grails3

I have a domain like this:

```
class Container {
  Content content
}

class Content {
}

class ContentAlpha extends Content {
  String name
}

class ContentBeta extends Content {
  int length
}
```

Then I have a criteria:

```
def result = Container.withCriteria {
  content {
    eq('name', 'Pablo')
  }
}
```

How can I get all the containers that contain just ContentAlpha that match the value given for the 'name'?

Answer (score -1):

I think the `withCriteria` closure you are trying to use is conceptually wrong, from the OOP perspective.

Generally speaking, a superclass does not contain information about its subclasses. In contrast, a subclass does contain information about its superclass.

In your example, an instance of `ContentAlpha` is a `Content` also. But, an instance of `Content` is not a `ContentAlpha`. Therefore, you cannot query `content.name`, because `name` does not exists as a property of `Content` class.

Having said that, let me suggest a rudimentary tip (acknowledging that I don't know the context of the problem you are trying to solve, and assuming you can't change your domains' relations):

You could add a couple of static functions in `Container.groovy`:

```groovy
static def queryContent(String name) {
   return Container.findAllByContentInList(ContentAlpha.findAllByName(name))
}
    
static def queryContent(int length) {
   return Container.findAllByContentInList(ContentBeta.findAllByLength(length))
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```groovy
def containersA = Container.queryContent("Pablo")
def containersB = Container.queryContent(4000)
```

Comment: Hi @rchfox not sure what this means "a superclass does not contain information about its subclasses. In contrast, a subclass does contain information about its superclass" in plain SQL I would do a container JOIN content, and filter by type to query on the specific column, since length will be null in the content table for ContentAlpha, I still can query by name. But is the type check what I'm missing in the Grails criteria. So this is not that container doesn't have info about it's content, I don't need such info, but I do need to containers that actually contain something that matches xxx.

Comment: The issue with `return Container.findAllByContentInList(ContentAlpha.findAllByName(name))` is all the ContentAlpha need to be retrieved in order to match the container, which could not have a good performance. I would prefer to resolve it in the query instead of in memory, if possible of course.

Comment: I concur with @PabloPazos.  This approach is going to be problematic for a lot of data sets.